# Plot argmax of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with shape (20,20,6).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

num_channels = 6
a = np.random.choice(range(100),(20,20,num_channels))
```

I want to get an array with shape (20,20,4), 20x20 times an RGBA colour indicating which value in `a` is the argmax along the last axis. Therefore, I generate 6 RGBA colours and take the argmax over `a`.

```py
color_list = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, num_channels))
a = a.argmax(axis=-1)
```

now `a` has dimensions `20x20`. How do I get it to `20x20x4` using the colour list?

This is what the colour list looks like:

```
[[0.5  0.   1.   1.  ]
 [0.1  0.59 0.95 1.  ]
 [0.3  0.95 0.81 1.  ]
 [0.7  0.95 0.59 1.  ]
 [1.   0.59 0.31 1.  ]
 [1.   0.   0.   1.  ]]
```

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to do... What are the six initial channels in your matrix / image representing? The usual way to do this is converting whatever color space you're coming from to RGBA for each pixel, then affect your new matrix in a loop...

Comment: I want to get a 20 x 20 picture where each pixel color represents a value 0 to 5, the argmax of „a“ along the last axis. The Original Array is not an image. It’s data. And it is actually 1000x1000x20 or so and I have 10k of these

Comment: so you want to "flatten" your 6 dimensions into 1 based on the argmax of given pixel?

Comment: @Tartempion yes. And then in the new matrix of 20x20 I want Color1 for argmax=0, Color2 for argmax=1 etc

Comment: ok. give me 1 sec, if I can find out something...

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```py
import random

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# get colormap
num_channels = 6
color_list = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, num_channels))

# generate an array
a = np.random.rand(20,20,6)
a = np.argmax(a, axis=-1)
print(a)

# create new array
new_data = np.zeros((20,20,4))

for i in range(20):
    for j in range(20):
        # put RGBA value in new_data
        color = color_list[a[i][j]]
        new_data[i][j][:] = color

print(new_data)
```

Please mark this question as solved if it helped you!